# How to get index using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0

Given a datasource like that:

```
var c = new Car[]
{
  new Car{ Color="Blue", Price=28000},
  new Car{ Color="Red", Price=54000},
  new Car{ Color="Pink", Price=9999},
  // ..
};
```

How can I find the **index** of the first car satisfying a certain condition with LINQ?

EDIT:

I could think of something like this but it looks horrible:

```
int firstItem = someItems.Select((item, index) => new    
{    
    ItemName = item.Color,    
    Position = index    
}).Where(i => i.ItemName == "purple")    
  .First()    
  .Position;
```

Will it be the best to solve this with a plain old loop?

Comment: Similar: [get-list-element-position-in-c-sharp-using-linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110789/get-list-element-position-in-c-sharp-using-linq)

Comment: Even this information would be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049773/how-to-use-index-position-with-where-in-linq-query-language

Comment: Actually there is an `index` statement: `var result = items.Select((item, index) => new { index, item });`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` is not an ordered set.
Although most IEnumerables are ordered, some (such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet`) are not.

Therefore, LINQ does not have an `IndexOf` method.

However, you can write one yourself:

```
///<summary>Finds the index of the first item matching an expression in an enumerable.</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search.</param>
///<param name="predicate">The expression to test the items against.</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if no items match.</returns>
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

    int retVal = 0;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (predicate(item)) return retVal;
        retVal++;
    }
    return -1;
}
///<summary>Finds the index of the first occurrence of an item in an enumerable.</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search.</param>
///<param name="item">The item to find.</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if the item was not found.</returns>
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T item) { return items.FindIndex(i => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, i)); }
```

Comment: Although it does have an ElementAt method. Which takes an index as the argument.

Comment: Yes; I don't know why that method exists.

Comment: C# has a Predicate delegate for you, how come you used Func<T, bool>?

Comment: Because that's what all of the other LINQ methods use.  It makes the delegate signature clearer in the tooltip.  `Predicate`, `Comparison`, and friends were effectively replaced by the `Func` delegates in .Net 3.5.

Comment: @SLaks, since this method already exists and is well known in the `List<T>` class, you should name it `FindIndex` and it should take a `Predicate<T>` instead of `Func<T, bool>`. The `IndexOf` takes a `T` object instead of a selector. Remember, consistency is the #1 strong point of the CLI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx

Comment: @280Z28: LINQ is already inconsist with `List<T>` - `FindAll(Predicate<T>)` vs. `Where(Func<T, bool>)`, `Exists(Predicate<T>)` vs. `Any(Func<T, bool>)`, `ConvertAll(Converter<T, TOutput>)` vs. `Select(Func<T1, T2>)`, etc.

Comment: @SLaks: That may be true, but 1) in each case, the new name does not alias a name present in a similar context earlier versions, 2) for FindAll/Where and ConvertAll/Select, the new version has different semantics, and the old name doesn't make sense in a lazy-evaluation context, and 3) for Exists/Any, the old name is misleading. You use this as a rationale for your answer, but you didn't follow #1, #2 certainly doesn't apply, and #3 is debatable at best.

Comment: @SLaks: With all the other methods that rely on the order (ElementAt, First, Last, Skip and friends) I don't think IndexOf would be too far-fetched.

Comment: The first bit is confusing and should be rephrased/deleted. `IEnumerable` exposes an `IEnumerator`, which has two members: `MoveNext()` and `Current` - it's inherently ordered.

Comment: This is already found in the Metadata of System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 948):

```
myCars.Select((v, i) => new {car = v, index = i}).First(myCondition).index;
```

or the slightly shorter

```
myCars.Select((car, index) => new {car, index}).First(myCondition).index;
```

or the slightly shorter shorter

```
myCars.Select((car, index) => (car, index)).First(myCondition).index;
```

Comment: I just used this and it works fine for me.  how does this differ from the marked answer?

Comment: You are using ordered collection (such as Car[]), thus marked answer doesn't apply to your case... you couldn't use this on Dictionary or Hashset.

Comment: @kape123: This certainly also can be used for `Dictionary` and `Hashset`. Obviously the index returned isn't as "well defined" as an index in an ordered collection, but it can still be used with `ElementAt` to retrieve the matched element.

Comment: The big difference is that this will throw an exception if myCondition is not met by any of the items where as the marked answer returns -1 in that case.

Comment: @ProfK be careful with the `FirstOrDefault`, the default of a class in null, calling .index on a null with throw an exception.

Comment: @AaronAnodide, see juharr's comment. I recommend against using this method if you want to be able to handle cases where no items match.

Comment: Just commenting for future searchers that C#6 will allow `myCars.Select((car, index) => new {car, index}).FirstOrDefault(myCondition)?.index;` to return a null index when handling cases where there are no results after myCondition is applied.

Comment: Handing ´myCondition´ to ´FirstOrDefault()´ means the function must accept an anonymous type, so ´a => myCondition(a.car)´ should be handed over. I used this implementation and made the result nullable, which is fine for me. But you could use ´?.index ?? -1´ to get the same result of the marked answer when the condition does not hit at all.

Comment: This is correct answer and the answer mark should be awarded to this one.

Answer (score 227):

Simply do :

```
int index = List.FindIndex(your condition);
```

E.g.

```
int index = cars.FindIndex(c => c.ID == 150);
```

Comment: +1 - although LINQ deals only with IEnumerable, this answer made me realize that in my case it was OK to convert the IEnumerable to list and then call `FindIndex`

Comment: For arrays just use `Array.FindIndex`.

Comment: @beluchin Keep in mind, if you convert the `IEnumerable` to `List` the `IEnumerable` is not lazy any more. You are forcing to obtain **Every** elements of it, even you don't actually need them.

Comment: This is a perfect solution, as long as you're using a unique condition. In other cases, when it is possible that multiple elements match, you will not get a list of indices, but only the first element of it.

Answer (score 90):

```
myCars.TakeWhile(car => !myCondition(car)).Count();
```

It works! Think about it. The index of the first matching item equals the number of (not matching) item before it.

## Story time

I too dislike the *horrible standard solution* you already suggested in your question. Like the accepted answer I went for a plain old loop although with a slight modification:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (predicate(item)) break;
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Note that it will return the number of items instead of `-1` when there is no match. But let's ignore this minor annoyance for now. In fact the *horrible standard solution* crashes in that case and [I consider returning an index that is out-of-bounds superior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

What happens now is ReSharper telling me [Loop can be converted into LINQ-expression](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp60/Code_Analysis__Examples_of_Quick-Fixes.html#loop_to_LINQ). While most of the time the feature worsens readability, this time the result was awe-inspiring. So Kudos to the JetBrains.

## Analysis

#### Pros

- Concise
- Combinable with other LINQ
- Avoids `new`ing anonymous objects
- Only evaluates the enumerable until the predicate matches for the first time

Therefore I consider it optimal in time and space while remaining readable.

#### Cons

- Not quite obvious at first
- Does not return `-1` when there is no match

Of course you can always hide it behind an extension method. And what to do best when there is no match heavily depends on the context.

Comment: adding simple isFound boolean before loop, setting this variable to true before break statement and comparing to it before returning from function would solve -1 problem

Comment: I actually needed a LINQ query that would return the full count if no item was found, so this is perfect!

Comment: `return index` instead of `break` inside loop would retain functionality and readability and make easy to convert last `return` to return -1 if no element is found.

Answer (score 14):

I will make my contribution here... why? just because :p Its a different implementation, based on the Any LINQ extension, and a delegate. Here it is:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOf<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> list, 
            Predicate<T> condition) {               
        int i = -1;
        return list.Any(x => { i++; return condition(x); }) ? i : -1;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    TestGetsFirstItem();
    TestGetsLastItem();
    TestGetsMinusOneOnNotFound();
    TestGetsMiddleItem();   
    TestGetsMinusOneOnEmptyList();
}

void TestGetsFirstItem()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

    // Act
    int index = list.IndexOf(item => item.Equals("a"));

    // Assert
    if(index != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index should be 0 but is: " + index);
    }

    "Test Successful".Dump();
}

void TestGetsLastItem()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

    // Act
    int index = list.IndexOf(item => item.Equals("d"));

    // Assert
    if(index != 3)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index should be 3 but is: " + index);
    }

    "Test Successful".Dump();
}

void TestGetsMinusOneOnNotFound()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

    // Act
    int index = list.IndexOf(item => item.Equals("e"));

    // Assert
    if(index != -1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index should be -1 but is: " + index);
    }

    "Test Successful".Dump();
}

void TestGetsMinusOneOnEmptyList()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new string[] {  };

    // Act
    int index = list.IndexOf(item => item.Equals("e"));

    // Assert
    if(index != -1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index should be -1 but is: " + index);
    }

    "Test Successful".Dump();
}

void TestGetsMiddleItem()
{
    // Arrange
    var list = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

    // Act
    int index = list.IndexOf(item => item.Equals("c"));

    // Assert
    if(index != 2)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index should be 2 but is: " + index);
    }

    "Test Successful".Dump();
}
```

Comment: By the way, the code is runnable on the LINQPad

Answer (score 6):

Here is a little extension I just put together.

```
public static class PositionsExtension
{
    public static Int32 Position<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                          Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Positions<TSource>(source, predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Int32> Positions<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                                        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (typeof(TSource) is IDictionary)
        {
            throw new Exception("Dictionaries aren't supported");
        }

        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("source is null");
        }
        if (predicate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("predicate is null");
        }
        var found = source.Where(predicate).First();
        var query = source.Select((item, index) => new
            {
                Found = ReferenceEquals(item, found),
                Index = index

            }).Where( it => it.Found).Select( it => it.Index);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this.

```
IEnumerable<Int32> indicesWhereConditionIsMet = 
      ListItems.Positions(item => item == this);

Int32 firstWelcomeMessage ListItems.Position(msg =>               
      msg.WelcomeMessage.Contains("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of the highest-voted answer that returns -1 when the item is not found:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var itemsWithIndices = items.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index });
    var matchingIndices =
        from itemWithIndex in itemsWithIndices
        where predicate(itemWithIndex.Item)
        select (int?)itemWithIndex.Index;

    return matchingIndices.FirstOrDefault() ?? -1;
}
```

Comment: Just use DefaultIfEmpty(-1)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks; I don't think I've used that method before. How is it better than the way I've done it here? Do you think it's more readable?