# How to use index/position with Where in LINQ query language?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there any possibility to write this using query language ... not method chain?

```
 notifications.Where((n, index) => n.EventId == m_lastSelectedEventID)
              .Select((n, index) => new {Position = index}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks, 
Radu

Comment: Why? Plus this looks a lot like the output is `AnonymousClass1 { Position = 1 }` or `NULL`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, query expression syntax doesn't have support for those overloads I'm afraid.

On the other hand, if you use the Select overload explicitly *once* at the start to create an anonymous type with the index and value in, you can then use that sequence of pairs within a query expression. For example:

```
var query = from pair in sequence.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
            where pair.index % 3 == 0
            select string.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.index, pair.value);
```

EDIT: Note that in your sample code, you're always filtering first and then taking the index of the first entry in the *result* sequence. That index will always be 0. If you want to actually find the *original* index of the selected ID within `notifications`, I suspect you really want:

```
int? index = notifications.Select((n, index) => new { n, index })
                          .Where(pair => pair.n.EventId == m_lastSelectedEventID)
                          .Select(pair => (int?) pair.index)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

(That will return a `Nullable<int>` of `null` if not found.)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the performance if you invert where and select? Is there any difference?

Comment: @Radu: Well, it'll give different *results* apart from anything else. I'll edit my question to explain.

Comment: Another way instead of the `int?`: `...Where(...).Select(p => i.index).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First()`.

Comment: @Radu D - I think about it this way. In the moment I use Select there will need to be something I can select from. It'll be defined by the part of the query that appears before select.