# Can we use overloaded Where operator in LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq

This sample demonstrates an indexed Where clause that returns digits whose name is shorter than their value.
Source Code

```
public void Linq5() 
{ 
    string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }; 

    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index); 

    Console.WriteLine("Short digits:"); 
    foreach (var d in shortDigits) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("The word {0} is shorter than its value.", d); 
    } 
}
```

Now My Question is ...Can we write this in the LINQ Query format like:

```
from u in digits where u.Length>index select u;
```

Here How to get the INDEX value from above Query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ where using index in query language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049773/linq-where-using-index-in-query-language)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049773/linq-where-using-index-in-query-language

Answer (score 1):

No, overloaded `Where` operator is not available in query syntax. Here is quote from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx):

> In query expression syntax, a *where* (Visual C#) or Where (Visual
>   Basic) clause translates to an invocation of
>   `Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`

You can introduce index manually:

```
int index = 0;
var query = from u in digits 
            where u.Length > index++ 
            select u;
```

But keep in mind that you should also manually reset index before each query invocation. Anyway - if you need index, then fluent API is the best choice for you:

```
var query = digits.Where((u, i) => u.Length > i);
```

I don't see any reason why not to use it.

Comment: Thanks...Is there any other option..?

Comment: @user1849388 I've added link to msdn, which points how query syntax translated into Where operator. Problem is that you should pass `Func<T,bool>` to where clause in query syntax. You can't add some additional parameter there. And I'm still don't understand why you don't want to use `Where((u, i) => u.Length > i)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var shortDigits = from pair in digits.Select((digit, index) => new { digit, index })
              where pair.digit.Length < pair.index
              select pair.digit;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what exactly I'm looking for. btw, what is he difference between the Select and Where? I think both operators are doing the same work?

Comment: Select is usually used when you need to iterate ALL the elements of the enumeration and return something for those elements (in my example a pair of values).
While Where is usually used to restrict the enumeration to a list of elements that satisfy a given condition.
P.S. I my answer was useful for you consider accepting and upvoting it ;)