# Using C# Linq to return first index of null/empty occurrence in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of strings called "Cars"

I would like to get the first index of the array is either null, or the value stored is empty.  This is what I got so far:

```
private static string[] Cars;
Cars = new string[10];
var result = Cars.Where(i => i==null || i.Length == 0).First();
```

But how do I get the first INDEX of such an occurrence?

For example:

```
Cars[0] = "Acura";
```

then the index should return 1 as the next available spot in the array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [**`Array.FindIndex`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx)   method for this purpose.

> Searches for an element that matches
>   the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate, and returns the
>   zero-based index of the first
>   occurrence within the entire Array.

For example:

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(Cars, i => i == null || i.Length == 0);
```

For a more general-purpose method that works on any `IEnumerable<T>`, take a look at: [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq).

Comment: If these are strings, why not use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)`

Answer (score 5):

If you want the LINQ way of doing it, here it is:

```
var nullOrEmptyIndices =
    Cars
        .Select((car, index) => new { car, index })
        .Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.car))
        .Select(x => x.index);

var result = nullOrEmptyIndices.First();
```

Maybe not as succinct as `Array.FindIndex`, but it will work on any `IEnumerable<>` rather than only arrays. It is also composable.