# Get Row Index in a list by using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 5 datas in my list.

**MyList**

So i want to know , how can i get selected Id's Row Number ?

```
var MyProductId= 135;
var SelectedDataRowNumber = context.SP_MyList.ToList()
                                   .Where(s=>s.Id==MyProductId)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

As instance,
My List has 5 datas like below,

```
Id-Name

6,Computer

135,KeyBoard

68,Mouse

98,Telephone

213,Laptop,
```

`MyProductId` is `135` so it matchs with Keyboard.It is row count number( index )must be "1" because 0 is Computer.

How can i get selected Id's row count(index) number ?

Comment: what do you mean by Row number? Can you please add some example data, of what the objects in your list look like?

Comment: I updated please check

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2471631/665689

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it directly the element by Index if your list has implemented indexer. You can find that [How to implement Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Another way could be as described in [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/236792/how-to-get-index-of-list-item-in-Csharp).

The above link shows it like:

**COPIED From Above link:**

```
Person agedTwenty = myList.Where<Person>( x => return x.Age == 20; ).Single<Person>();
int index = myList.IndexOf(agedTwenty);
```

or alternatively

```
int index = myList.Where<Person>( x => return x.Age == 20; ).Select<Person,int>( x =>         
myList.IndexOf(x)).Single<int>();
```

In case there can be more than one result you'd do this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> allAgedTwenty = myList.Where<Person>( x => return x.Age == 20; );
IEnumerable<int> indices = allAgedTwenty.Select<Person,int>( x => myList.IndexOf(x) );
```

The first case will get you only one int and the second case will leave you with a list of ints.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the count you need to groupBy

```
var SelectedDataRowNumber = context.SP_MyList.ToList()
                                   .GroupBy(x = x.Id)
                                   .Where(s=>s.Key == MyCustomerId )
                                   .Select(x => new {Id = x.Key, Count = x.Count()});
```

This gives you the output

```
Id = 135
Count = 3 //depending on the actual count
```

alternative solution, if you want to output id, name and count:

```
//"items" is my custom list I created to reflect your data
var SelectedDataRowNumber = from x in items 
                            group x by new {x.Id, x.Name} into g
                            where g.Key.Id == 135
                            select new 
                            {
                                ID = g.Key.Id, 
                                Name = g.Key.Name, 
                                Count = g.Count()
                            };
```

Regarding your comment: is this the result you are expecting: http://abload.de/img/so1j5rta.jpg ?

Comment: SelectedDataRowNumber .Count is always 1 i do not know why

Comment: If you take `SelectedDataRowNumber.Count()` it will be always 1 if you grouped by Id and filtered it by Id afterwards. The count you want is in the result set.