# Order a couple of synchronized lists based on a selected list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have two lists in c# as follows:

- X    ,  Y
- 0.2 ,   5.4
- 0.6  ,  4.1
- 0.9   , 6.7
- 10.58,  45.7
- -1.54, -7.02
- 6.5  ,  6.66

Now, I would like to order the list of X but I would like the list of Y to sync with X's re-ordering.

Re-ordered list would look like:

- X    ,  Y
- -1.54, -7.02
- 0.2 ,   5.4
- 0.6  ,  4.1
- 0.9   , 6.7
- 6.5  ,  6.66
- 10.58,  45.7

Any way of doing this using LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to have two lists? A single list where each element is the pair of values would almost certainly be cleaner. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Comment: Hi Jon, I have done this for performance reasons - having structure of arrays rather than arrays of structures... The lists can be 10K - 25K elements long and accessing and filtering these are quicker with SOA.

Comment: Not sure where SOA comes in, but it should be pretty trivial to access and filter them. Are your performance concerns theoretical, or have you actually *tried* this the more logical (IMO) way and found it to be too slow?

Comment: By SOA I meant structure of Arrays. Didn't mean to confuse it with Service oriented architecture. Yes, this was done post performance testing using profiling tools.

Answer (score 1):

**1. `Array.Sort<TKey, TValue>(keys, value)` method**

If your lists are actually `System.Array`s or you do not care about few additional copying due to `ToArray` calls, then the simplest way is to use the [`Array.Sort<TKey, TValue>(keys, value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
public static IList<Double> GetKeys()
{
    return new Double[] 
    {
        0.2,
        0.6, 
        0.9,
        10.58,
        -1.54,
        6.5
    }; 
}

public static IList<Double> GetValues()
{
    return new Double[]
    {
        5.4,
        4.1,
        6.7,
        45.7,
        -7.02,
        6.66
    };
}


public static void Print<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static void PrintKeyValues<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (keys == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keys");
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

    var pairs = keys
        .Zip(values,
            (key, value) =>
                String.Format("[{0}] = {1}", key, value));

    Print(pairs);
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var keys = GetKeys();
    var values = GetValues();

    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    PrintKeyValues(keys, values);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("After");

    var keysArray = keys.ToArray();
    var valuesArray = values.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(keysArray, valuesArray);

    PrintKeyValues(keysArray, valuesArray);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**2. Nearly pure LINQ**

If you need LINQ solution, then you obviously have no problems with excessive copying. So, you  have to sort one array, while preserving the indices with [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq) and then shuffle the associated array:

```
public static T[] ShuffleFromIndices<T>(this IList<T> items, IList<Int32> indices)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (indices == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("indices");
    if (items.Count != indices.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("items and indices have different lengths");

    T[] result = new T[items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        var shuffleIndex = indices[i];

        result[i] = items[shuffleIndex];
    }

    return result;
}

public static Tuple<TKey[], TValue[]> SortNotInPlace<TKey, TValue>(IList<TKey> keys, IList<TValue> values)
{
    if (keys == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keys");
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    if (keys.Count != values.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Keys and values have different lengths");

    var sortedKeysWithIndices = keys
        .Select((key, index) =>
            new { key, index })
        .OrderBy(keyIndex => keyIndex.key);

    var shuffleIndices = sortedKeysWithIndices
        .Select(keyIndex => keyIndex.index)
        .ToArray();

    var sortedValues = values.ShuffleFromIndices(shuffleIndices);

    var sortedKeys = sortedKeysWithIndices
            .Select(keyIndex => keyIndex.key)
            .ToArray();

    return new Tuple<TKey[], TValue[]>(sortedKeys,
        sortedValues);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var keys = GetKeys();
    var values = GetValues();

    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    PrintKeyValues(keys, values);


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("With LINQ");

    var sorted = SortNotInPlace(keys, values);
    var sortedKeys = sorted.Item1;
    var sortedValues = sorted.Item2;
    PrintKeyValues(sortedKeys, sortedValues);

    Console.ReadKey();            
}
```

**3. High performance**

If you really care about performance and need no-additional-memory in-place sorting, then you will have to implement your own `Sort` method, that synchronously sorts both lists.