# How to find a one dimensional array in a two dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a two dimensional array namely States. I create a one dimensional array, say SubState. Then I change SubState. I want to find new SubState in States and get the index. As an example:

```
int[][] States = new int[3][] { new int[] { 3, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 2, 5, 1 }, new int[] { 2, 3, 4 } };
int[] SubState = new int[States[0].Length];
States[0].CopyTo(SubState, 0);
SubState[0] -= 1;
```

I want to find the index of new SubState in State, which will be 2 in the example.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve? Your question doesn't make much sense and this approach doesn't seem very flexible or maintainable.

Comment: FYI that's not a 2 dimensional array, that's a jagged array.  A 2 dimensional array would be defined as `int[3,3]`.

Comment: I have a two dimensional array which contains some one dimensional arrays. Some of these arrays differ each other in one element. For example [3,3,4] differs with [2,3,4] & [3,2,4] &[3,3,3] in one element by 1. I want to find indices of these three arrays in the the main two dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a beginner, I have made a lot of mistakes :).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `SequenceEqual`:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < States.Length; i++)
    if (States[i].SequenceEqual(SubState))
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
```

If you define a LINQ [`FindIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471631/1149773) operator, you can express it more concisely using:

```
int index = States.FindIndex(s => s.SequenceEqual(SubState));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped. It would be appreciated if you tell me how to define a LINQ FindIndex operator too. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Mohebbi: You can copy the implementation from the linked answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2471631/1149773

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SequenceEqual` method inside a LINQ query, like this:

```
var nextStateIndex = States
    .Select((a, i) => new {Index = i, Array = a})
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Array.SequenceEqual(SubState))
    ?.Index;
if (nextStateIndex.HasValue) {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** this code uses the new `?.` operator. If you are targeting C# version that does not have support for this operator, store  `FirstOrDefault` result for an explicit null checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
  var index = -1;

  var foundSubState = States.FirstOrDefault(x => {
    index++;
    return x.SequenceEqual(SubState);
  });

  var res = foundSubState != default(Array) ? index : -1;
```