# Entity lookup by row number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF, when having to deal with indexes, we need to convert the entity collection to a list as `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` do not implement any indexer (it would be meaningless due to the deferred execution mechanism). When having a pretty large collection using `ToList` for using indexes would be heavy.

This is why I sometimes need to look up entities by the row number (not the identity / primary key). For example, I have one record, I want to get its row number (position in the sorted table) and get the next record.

Can this be achieved in Entity Framework? I can send SQL queries to do this, but I'm curious if there is a Linqish and EF specific approach to do this.

Comment: have you tried `ElementAt()` method and this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq  ?

Comment: @Tim.Tang: That is way way off topic.

Comment: If you are having large list and need to do lookup by row number then consider using Skip/Take in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible through tweaking the DbContex and adding a fake entity that corresponds to the row number. This entity can be exploited for using the built-in `ROW_NUMBER()` function in SQL. For instance:

```
public class RowNumber{
    public Int64 Row_Number {get; set;}
}
```

followed by adding these two the DbContext

```
public virtual DbSet<RowNumber> RowNumber {get; set;}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RowNumber>(x => {
            x.HasKey(e => e.Row_Number);
        });
 ...
}
```

Now we can make the following query:

```
var rowNumber = dbContext.Set<RowNumber>().FromSql("SELECT Row_Number FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Column] DESC) AS Row_Number, [Column] FROM [Table]) AS Query WHERE [Column] = {0}").ToList();
```

And yeah this is more efficient and of higher performance!

Comment: Your example for `EF 6` or `EF Core`?