# FindIndex extension in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the indexes as follows.

But the following LINQ says there is no extension of `FindIndex`.

```
foreach (var distinctClassId in distinctClassIds)
{
    var indexes = classComponents.Where(x=> x.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId)).
                  FindIndex(x => x.Id == Constants.Classes.ClassID.ToString() ||
                   x.Id == Constants.Courses.CoursesID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq

Comment: What exactly should `FindIndex` do? You know that there is a `Where` overload that gives you the index of the current item as parameter to the predicate? And a `Select` overload as well?

Comment: `classComponents.Where(x=> x.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId))` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`  where as the FindIndex() method is applicable on List<T>.  Change following to `var indexes = classComponents.Where(x=> x.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId)).ToList().
                  FindIndex(x => x.Id == Constants.Classes.ClassID.ToString() ||
                   x.Id == Constants.Courses.CoursesID.ToString());`

Comment: To avoid confusion: you named the variable `indexes`, do you expect `FindIndex` to return _multiple_ indices? `FindIndex` only returns the index of the first item that matches the predicate...

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, it could be more than one.

Comment: ok, edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindIndex()` is an instance method of `List<T>`. But `Where()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (or maybe an `IQueryable<T>` depending on what `classComponents` is in your code).

So you need to convert that `Where` result to list before you can call `FindIndex()`:

```
foreach (var distinctClassId in distinctClassIds)
{
    var indexes = classComponents.Where(x=> x.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId)).ToList(). // here -> ToList()
                  FindIndex(x => x.Id == Constants.Classes.ClassID.ToString() ||
                   x.Id == Constants.Courses.CoursesID.ToString());
}
```

---

But `FindIndex()` only gives you the index of the **first** matching item. Your variable is called `indexes`, so you might want to find the indices of multiple matching items. This can be done by using the linq overloads that give you the index, too:

```
foreach (var distinctClassId in distinctClassIds)
{
    var filtered = classComponents.Where(x=> x.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId)).ToList();

    var indexes = filtered.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
                          .Where(x => x.item.Id == Constants.Classes.ClassID.ToString() ||
                   x.item.Id == Constants.Courses.CoursesID.ToString())
                          .Select(x => x.index);
}
```

This creates objects of anonymous type containing the item and its index, then checking which items match and finally returning their indices.

Note: if you actually wanted the indices in the source list (`classComponents`), you should combine the `Where` statements like that:

```
foreach (var distinctClassId in distinctClassIds)
{
    var indexes = classComponents.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
                    .Where(x => x.item.ClassId.Equals(distinctClassId) &&
                                (x.item.Id == Constants.Classes.ClassID.ToString() ||
                                 x.item.Id == Constants.Courses.CoursesID.ToString()))
                    .Select(x => x.index);
}
```