# LINQ selecting items from a list and saving their indices from the original list

Tags: c#, linq

I selected items from a list. How do I save their indices from the original list as well?

```cs
var originalList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 });
var selectedItems = originalList.Where(e => e > 5); // 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
```

An example:

selectedItems:

- (6, index = 5)
- (7, index = 6)
- (8, index = 7)
- and so on ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember indexes. It can be done via `Select` overload

```cs
var selectedItems = originalList
   .Select((e, index) => new { e, index })
   .Where(p => p.e > 5)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's correct. Only a small typo: it should be `(e, index) => new { e, index })`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible

```
var originalList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 });
var selectedItems = originalList.Select((e, i) => (e, i))
                                .Where(x => x.e > 5)
                                .Select(x => $"({x.e} , index = {x.i})") ;
```

Comment: I want their indices in `originalList`, and not `selectedItems`.

Comment: @nop, got your point. we just need to move select before where.. have updated the post

Comment: Yes, thanks! That way it works