# How can I utilize File.ReadLines instead of File.ReadAllLines in C# for this purpose

Tags: c#, performance, readline

Hi I am trying to make a program which ; takes an input txt file then shows its lines in reverse order

I was using File.ReadAllLines so I get a array of strings then I used indexes of the strings and used for loop to reverse the order.

But I did some research and found the File.ReadAllLines is not good for very long txt files so they say I should use File.ReadLines.

But I couldn't understand how to access the lines indexes as I did in string array

My working code is below ( which is written by using File.ReadAllLines) I want to do this with File.ReadLines How can I do this how can I access indexes if I use ReadlLines

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Txt Files Only |*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Load Log File";           
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        checkBox1.Checked = true;

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        checkBox1.Visible = false;
        button1.Visible = false;
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.Height = 200;
        textBox1.Width = 600;
        button2.Visible = false;
        textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        int n = lines.Length;
        for (int i = 0; n > i; n--)
        {
            textBox1.Text += lines[n - 1] + Environment.NewLine;
        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/452902/1977363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```cs
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
foreach (string line in lines.Reverse()) {
    ...
}
```

However, you won't get any performance benefit in this case, as the `Reverse()` operation will have to buffer all the lines. And this is precisely what `ReadLines` avoids doing by reading the lines lazily as you are looping through them.

Using `ReadAllLines` and a reverse for-loop is better in this case. But you can get a performance benefit by using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0):

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
for (int i = lines.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sb.AppendLine(lines[i]);
}
textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

The reason for this is that creating a string with repeated `+=` operations will create a new, lager string each time and copy the old value into the new one.

See also: [Use Visual C# to improve string concatenation performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/string-concatenation).

To increase the speed further, you could calculate the size of the resulting text in advance and use it to initialize the `StringBuilder` with an optimal buffer size.

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
var sb = new StringBuilder(lines.Sum(s => s.Length + 2));
```

Note: You can expand the [`forr` code snippet](https://dailydotnettips.com/codesnippet-for-reverse-for-loop/) in Visual Studio to get a reverse for loop.

Comment: firstly thanks, But how can I access the specific line if I use ReadLines. For example if I want to store the line number of some specific line how can I do that since ReadLines doesn't store index of the line (line number). Or if I don't want to read all lines in txt but only some specific numbered lines for example I want to read (or print) 345. lines to 350. lines. I believe I can not do that with Readlines since it doesn't know line number (row number). I think there is only foreach option to read the file so it reads all of the file. Can you help me on that

Comment: You can use LINQ extension methods: `lines.Skip(344).Take(6)`. In a foreach you can keep and update an index manually. Or you can have LINQ do it for you, see: [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471611/880990).

Answer (score 2):

To reverse the lines, you need to load all of them into memory anyway (unless you read from the bottom), so `File.ReadAllLines` is the correct choice.

> But I couldn't understand how to access the lines indexes as I did in
> string array

You can't. `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<String>`. IEnumerables can't be indexed. You could call `ToArray` or `ToList` to transform it to an array or list. In alternative, you can use `ElementAt` on the `IEnumerable` to get the value at the specified index. This is very inefficient, though.

Summary: Stick to `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: Yes... _for this purpose_. For many other purposes, `ReadLines()` does have a meaningful performance advantage over `ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: @tixina3684 But how can I access the specific line if I use ReadLines. For example if I want to store the line number of some specific line how can I do that since ReadLines doesn't store index of the line (line number). Or if I don't want to read all lines in txt but only some specific numbered lines for example I want to read (or print) 345. lines to 350. lines. I believe I can not do that with Readlines since it doesn't know line number (row number). I think there is only foreach option to read the file so it reads all of the file. Can you help me on that

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with File.ReadLines, since it returns an IEnumerable which is in this case implemented as a ReadLinesIterator. The iterator is only able to read one line at a time going forward. Anything that requires knowledge about all the lines (reversing them, counting them...) cannot be done without iterating through all lines first.

You could find lower-level approaches to do that, but it might be tricky.
**Anyway**, since you are displaying all the lines inside a textbox, you are keeping all the file's content in memory anyway. Looking for a more efficient way to read the file doesn't seem really useful in this case.