# Elegant way to retrieve the index of the max element from a List in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I am discovering the tools `C#` provides to work with collections.

Suppose I have a **List of elements**, and I want to retrieve the one that most satisfies a property. Basically a `elements.Max(predicate)`, except that I am interested in the **index of the best element**. The reason I want the index and not the element itself is there might not be such element, and the type is non-nullable.

Writing a function doing this is trivial, but I am interested in using the expressiveness of the tools C# provides to get a solution that is both *concise*, *clear*, and *optimal* (*O(n)*).

At this point I have the following code, which still looks cluttered, and evaluates the property twice.

```
List<foo> elements;
private int getBest(object x)
{
  var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, elements.Count);
  return indices.Aggregate(-1, (best, next) =>
    (-1 == best || eval(x, elements[next]) > eval(x, elements[best])) ? next : best);
}
```

How can I make this piece of code better?

---

**Addendum:** I didn't put it in the code for the sake of clarity, but if `eval()` is below a certain threshold the element is discarded.

Comment: You should be able to cache the score of the best as well as its index, so you only have to do the property evaluation once.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq)

Comment: Presumably the only way there could not be such an element is for the list to be empty, or did you mean something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq)

Comment: @AakashM: I edited the question regarding your comment.

Comment: Makes sense. Following the approach in the proposed duplicate will still work, I think.

Comment: See [get-list-element-position-in-c-sharp-using-linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110789/get-list-element-position-in-c-sharp-using-linq?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `Select` in conjunction with `Aggregate` LINQ extension methods. Using the `Select` method you can create an anonymous type which houses the `index` and `value` of each item within your collection. Then using the LINQ `Aggregate` method, you can narrow down the item with the greatest value. Some like this should work I think:

```
private int GetIndexOfHighestValue(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    return list.Select((i, v) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
        .Aggregate((a, b) => (a.Value > b.Value) ? a : b)
        .Index;
}
```

Comment: Certainly much cleaner than my code snippet already, thanks! (there is still the double evaluation problem though)

Comment: Forget my remark on evaluation. Applied to my example, in the `Select` part we have `Value = eval(x, v)` and we're happy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with LINQ is fun, but doing it without LINQ makes it more intuitive:

```
int bestIndex = -1;
int bestResult = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < elements.Count; ++i)
{
    int currentResult = eval(x, elements[i]);
    if (currentResult > bestResult)
    {
        bestResult = currentResult;
        bestIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. Writing it is easy, but it takes some time to read and figure out. I am looking for what the language offers to write something really elegant and crystal clear, like for example `var best = elements.MaxBy(y => eval(x, y))`.

Comment: You can do `elements.Max(e => eval(x, e))`, but this will always yield an element. I would split the eval into some filter method and an actual calculation. This way you can do `elements.Where(e => qualifies(e)).Max(e => eval(x, e))` for example.

Comment: @JulienGuertault Wrap this in a suitable extension method and you're done. Note that your example is NOT something "the language offers" - it's something a *library* offers. And the internals of that library look like this code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like <strike>this could work</strike>:

```
// OOPS: This won't work because Max is defined the way it is. Always bugged me...
var result = elements.Select((e, i) => new {Element = e, Index = i}).Max(x => x.Element).Select(x => x.Index);
```

oh rats. Right. This will not work. So: Let's pull out our allrounder: [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744). Here we go:

```
var elements = new List<int>{1, 7, 2, 5};
var result = elements.Select((e, i) => new {Element = e, Index = i})
    .Aggregate(
        new { Element = elements.First(), Index = -1}, // gotta start somewhere and Element is non-nullable according to OP
        (max, next) => (max.Element > next.Element) && max.Index >= 0 ? max : next,
        max => max.Index);
```

This results in `1`. Did that help?

Comment: No, it will not work. The `.Max` extension method returns directly the maximum element. There's no longer an `Index` property so your final `.Select` statement won't compile. The .Select extension method operates on `IEnumerable<T>` but `.Max` returns `T`.